# Add an alert (or change the "Add to Cart" button) after adding product to cart in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I have this snippet of JavaScript below. I want to add an alert after adding a product to a cart, or, change the "Add to Cart" button somehow, or, anything, to show the user that he has already added the product to the cart.

```
N.extend({
         isReady: false,
         add: function(e, t) {
             var n = e || {},
                 r = new N.Item(n),
                 i = true,
                 s = t === true ? t : false,
                 u;
             if (!s) {
                 i = N.trigger("beforeAdd", [r]);
                 if (i === false) {
                     return false
                 }
             }
             u = N.has(r);
             if (u) {
                 u.increment(r.quantity());
                 r = u
             } else {
                 o[r.id()] = r
             }
             N.update();
             if (!s) {
                 N.trigger("afterAdd", [r, a(u)])
             }
             return r
         },
```

What should my next step be?

Comment: Formatting, please-- use four spaces to format as code, and you need to add in newlines yourself.

Comment: Thanks! That's a lot better.